# Input carregando dados do Modal

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

Boa tarde!
Estou tentando fazer um modal pra buscar os produtos e atribuir ele ao input.
Idéia: Quando eu clicar no input, ele abre o modal. Depois eu escolho o produto no modal e ele carregar no input com os dados do produto escolhido.

Input que recebe o nome do produto (Tem um input hidden pra armazenar o id do produto também):

```
<td>
     <input type="text" name="produtoNF[0].nome" value="${produtoNF[0].nome}" onclick="getProduto()"/>
</td>
```

Modal que escolhe o produto:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="findProduct" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Buscar produto</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <ul id="ulItens" style="list-style-type: none">
                        <c:forEach itens="${productList}" var="product">                            
                            <li>                                    
                                <span>${product.id}</span> - 
                                <span>${product.nome}</span>
                            </li>                           
                        </c:forEach>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Java Script:

```
        function getPessoa() {
            $("#busPes").modal("show");
        }

        function setPessoa(id, nome) {
            $('#id').val(id);
            $('#nome').val(nome);
            $('#busPes').modal('hide');
        }
```

Consegui fazendo um input estático, porem quando crio o input dinâmico, (tenho um button que cria mais uma linha na tabela com inputs), não estou conseguindo entender como faço pra armazenar o valor escolhido no modal no input que eu clico para abrir o modal.

Como estou começando, tive dificuldade em explicar também.
Obrigado.

Comment: Você poderia postar o javascript que está utilizando no processo?

Comment: @LenilsondeCastro, tinha feito isso pra pessoa que era só um input estático. Coloquei no post o javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A minha proposta é um exemplo de como você pode implementar isso com os recursos do jQuery.

Primeiramente, os campos que vão armazenar e disparar o "product picker".

```
<td>
     <input type="text" id="myProductInput" name="produtoNF[0].nome" value="${produtoNF[0].nome}" />
     <input type="hidden" id="myProductInputId" name="produtoNF[0].id" value="${produtoNF[0].id}"/>
</td>
```

Depois o modal. Nada mudou além das linhas que desenham as `li`s com o código e o nome do produto.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="findProduct" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Buscar produto</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <ul id="ulItens" style="list-style-type: none">
                        <c:forEach itens="${productList}" var="product">                            
                            <li data-produce data-product-id="${product.id}" data-product-name="${product.nome}">                                    
                                <span>${product.id}</span> - 
                                <span>${product.nome}</span>
                            </li>                           
                        </c:forEach>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

E por fim, o javascript configurando os eventos do modal e dos produtores de resultado utilizando a API de promises do jQuery para gerenciar atividades asyncronas.

```
var $modal =  $("#busPes");

// para todo e qualquer elemento que quando clicado irá retornar (produzir) um produto.     
$modal.find('[data-produce]').click(function (e) {
    // caso exista um deferimento previamente registrado, o resolve com o produto clicado
    // o deferimento é uma forma de vinculo entre o modal e o input que solicitou o produto.
    if($modal.deferred){
        $modal.deferred.resolve({
            id: $(this).data('productId'),
            name: $(this).data('productName')
        });
    }

    $modal.modal("hide");
});

$modal.on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
  // cancela o deferimento atual pois o modal foi fechado
  delete $modal.deferred;
});

// ao clicar no input, dispara o mecanismo de chamar o modal pegador de produtos
$('#myProductInput').click(function (e) {
    var $this = $(this);

    $modal.modal("show");

    var deferred = $.Deferred();
    // registra o deferimento no modal para receber o valor produzido
    $modal.deferred = deferred;
    // por fim, registra os valores nos inputs quando o modal devolver o produto
    deferred.done(function(product) {

        $this.val(product.name);
        $('#myProductInputId').val(product.id);
    });
});
```

Comment: Muito obrigado!!